# SQL Query Select Count(*) AS grouped

Tags: sql, count, group

can someone help me to take the number of grouped products from a table to pass them to a recyclerview?
My code works fine with a simple query, but when I want to count grouped data it doesn't work
I hope you can help me. thank you so much!!

I am working with Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2

This is the part of the code that I can't solve

```
public class DbDBMaster extends DbHelper {

    Context context;

    
   public ArrayList<Products> takeAmount() {

        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ArrayList<Products> listProducts= new ArrayList<>();
        Products products;
        Cursor cursorProducts;
    // This works fine: cursorProducts = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MYDBProducts+ " GROUP BY numberProd ", null);
        cursorProducts = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS amount,numberProd, nameProd FROM " + TABLE_MYDBProducts+ " GROUP BY numberProd ", null);

        if (cursorProducts.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                products = new Products();
                products.setAmount(cursorProducts.getInt(0));
                products.setNumberProd(cursorProducts.getString(1));
                products.setNameProd(cursorProducts.getString(2));
                listProducts.add(products);
            } while (cursorProducts.moveToNext());
        }
        cursorProducts.close();
        return listProducts;
    }
}
```

when I want to count grouped data it doesn't work

Comment: `SELECT (*) FROM ...` isn't valid syntax. Should be `SELECT * FROM ...`

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: You're right - I edited it - it's a comment anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
GROUP BY numberProd, nameProd
```

And let us know if it works

Comment: now it works correctly!
I must clarify that in class "Products" I had "amount" as "int" and I changed it to "string"
Your help has been helpful to me and I am very grateful.